# Number of palindromes in the alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am working on a homework problem involving finding palindromes from the alphabet. I believe I've figured out the first part, but am having trouble applying my method to work with the second part.

The first part of the problem is to find all of the 9 digit palindromes that can be made with all of the letters in the alphabet (26) only using each letter at most twice. I solved this by saying that one letter of 26 was chosen for the middle letter, one of 25 for the 4th and 6th, one of 24 for the 3rd and 7th, one of 23 for the 2nd and 8th, and finally one of 22 for the 1st and 9th. I then multiplied 26 X 25 X 24 X 23 X 22 to get 7893600.

The second part of the question asks to find how many palindromes of length 9 can be made from the alphabet. I am having trouble figuring out how to adapt my approach to first part to make it work for this scenario.

Comment: What's an example of a $9$ digit palindrome that only uses each letter once?

Comment: my mistake, I meant once on each side of the midpoint or twice on each side of the midpoint

Comment: Got it.  To handle multiples, I think you need to split into cases.  You've done $0$ duplicates.  You need to also count the generic patterns $AABBC$ and $AABCD$, both unordered.

Comment: Example $AABBC$:  there are $\binom {26}2$ ways to choose the doubled letters.  Then $24$ ways to choose the singleton. then $\binom 52$ ways to place the earlier doubleton and then $\binom 32$ ways to place the other doubleton.

Comment: Note:  I still don't quite get the rules.  Does the palindrome $XXYZYZYXX$ count as using each letter at most twice?  Amongst the first five letters, I have used the $Y$ twice but one of those is the midpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'm looking at the question again now, and I think I may have misinterpreted it in an effort to not copy the exact question into my question (I'm trying to understand it not just get the answer :).) One part of the questions says solve for at most 2 of each letter which I believe I figured out In the first part of what I wrote above. The second part that I'm having trouble with is actually just to find the total number of palindromes using 9 of 26 letters.

Comment: I edited my above post as well to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

You did the first part alright.

For the second part: There are no restrictions whatsoever for the first five letters. When these have been written down the remaining four letters are determined.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So would it be 26 X 26 X 26 X 26 X 26 for the first five letters since it can be any of the 26 letters. The next four letters have to be in the same order so there is only one possible ordered set of them. So the answer would just be 26^5?